# Why do I get test loss 0 and accuracy 1.0 constant for all epochs?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, transfer-learning

I get test loss 0 and accuracy 1.0 for all epochs.
Calculate test loss with test loss = test loss / len(testloader)
and for accuracy = accuracy / len(testloader)

This can be seen below in the code
.....................................................................
.....................................................................

Screenshot:
[image]

Code :

```
device  = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = models.densenet121(pretrained=True)

for params in model.parameters():
  params.requires_grad = False

model.classifier = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
                                          ('fc1',nn.Linear(1024,256)),
                                          ('relu',nn.ReLU()),
                                          ('dropout',nn.Dropout(0.2)),
                                          ('fc2',nn.Linear(256,2)),
                                          ('output',nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))]))

criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.classifier.parameters(),lr = 0.003)

model.to(device)
epochs = 50
steps = 0 
running_loss = 0 
print_every = 5

for epoch in range(epochs):
  for inputs, labels in trainloader:
    steps +=1

    inputs,labels = inputs.to(device),labels.to(device)

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    logps = model.forward(inputs)
    loss = criterion(logps,labels)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    running_loss += loss.item()

    if steps % print_every == 0:
      test_loss = 0
      accuracy = 0 

      model.eval()

      with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs,labels in testloader:
          inputs,labels = inputs.to(device),labels.to(device)

          logps = model.forward(inputs)
          batch_loss = criterion(logps,labels)

          test_loss += batch_loss.item()

          #calculate accuracy 
          ps = torch.exp(logps)
          top_p,top_class = ps.topk(1,dim=1)
          equals = top_class == labels.view(*top_class.shape)
          accuracy += torch.mean(equals.type(torch.FloatTensor)).item()
      
      print(f'Epoch : {epoch+1}/{epochs}..'
            f'Training loss : {running_loss/print_every:.3f}...'
            f'Test loss: {test_loss/len(testloader):.3f}.. '
            f'Test accuracy: {accuracy/len(testloader):.3f}')
      
      running_loss = 0
      model.train()
```

My dataset folder structure:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, avoid sharing images. It's usually better (for multiple reasons) to describe with words

Comment: Yeah okay, I just wanted to make my question clear. So, do you have a solution?